# Where can I find Hibernate's End of support - Support Lifecycle - updates

Tags: hibernate, hibernate3

Ours is a legacy product where it has its heavily hand-crafted hibernate API's based on 3.6.10.Final.

Now I want to evaluate the risk of not upgrading to 4.x or 5.x versions.
Upgrading is gonna be a nightmare, just to make it compiling.. :P

But I couldn't find any official info or contract or support pages mentioning the End of support notice on 3.6.10.Final releases [Any releases in general].

1. https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/jboss_notes/
   a. Section "Product Life Cycle Dates/Red Hat JBoss Web Server"
2. https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HHH?selectedItem=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:release-page&
   status=unreleased

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following

http://in.relation.to/2015/10/27/great-jira-cleanup-2015/

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/wiki/Huge-Project,-Small-Team

Which means they are already only supporting 5+ versions for security updates + bug fixed